# How to store store BackColore color as a method and the used it in a different method in C#

Tags: c#

I build a method that hold BackColor for a panel, if i call the method in a new method the color will not show

this is my code
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication24
{
    class theme
    {
        public static void dark()
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
           Color c= f.panel1.BackColor = Color.Black;

        }

    }
}

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication24
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           theme.dark();

        }
    }
}
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

---

Answer (score 1):

The `new Form1()` you instantiated is an instance of the `Form1` class, but many `Form1` instances can exist simultaneously. You want to pass the instance of `Form1` you are trying to change. Try:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  theme.dark(this);
}
```

And:

```
public static void dark(Form1 f)
{
  f.panel1.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```